# Control header position and font size

Tags: header-footer, margins, fontsize

I need to:

- place the page header 1 inch from the top of the page.
- change font size for the page header to be the same font size (\normalsize) as in the table of contents.

I've used `geometry` as below to set margins but still the header is quite far from top of the page.

```
\usepackage[
top    = 1in,
bottom = 1in,
left   = 1.25in,
right  = 1.25in]{geometry}
```

I also tried `fancyhdr` to change header font size but the header doesn't get smaller.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\normalsize}
```

What's the right way to control header's position and font size?

Thanks,

PS: `\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[
  top    = 1in,
  bottom = 1in,
  left   = 1.25in,
  right  = 1.25in,
  includehead,%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!!!!
  showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\normalsize foo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I still get very big gap from header to top of the page like [this](http://imgur.com/jmFloly). Note, I didn't use `\pagestyle{fancy}` as I don't need the horizontal line above every page.

Comment: In the options of geometry set `headsep=5mm,` or any other value.

Comment: I've just tried that without success. The header font is still big and the gap from top edge remains the same. Here's my config ```\usepackage[
top    = 1in,
bottom = 1in,
left   = 1.25in,
right  = 1.25in,
headsep=1mm,
includehead]{geometry}```

Comment: That makes no sense. Give a _complete_ example which shows your behaviour. In my example all works well.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/khanh-nguyen/dummy-text)'s the sample @Herbert